# Jquery with mask plugin not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, jquery-plugins, jquery-mask

Im using Jquery Mask Plugin:
http://plugins.jquery.com/mask/

My script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".txtday").mask('Z99', { reverse: true, translation: { 'Z': { pattern: /[0-1]/, optional: true}}, placeholder:"%" });
            });
        </script>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtday0" Width="25" CssClass="txtday" />
```

On IE 11 is working perfectly, but on Chrome just show like a normal textbox without mask.

Im coding asp.net with Visual Studio 2010.

If someone know something about that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the chrome developer tools (press F12 when chrome is open) and check the console, see if there are any errors.

Comment: @Paritosh nothing there, without erros.